# I am publishing some pages on mediawiki(1.33 version). I need to display one image in header of all pages when i take printout

Tags: printing, header, mediawiki

I tried different options by modifiying print.css and common.css pages given on google. But, nothing worked for me. I am using ie11 and google chrome 23.0.

Comment: What are you trying to do? and What did you change? and what is your expected output? Please explain it clearly with code and samples.

Comment: @Thangadurai, Thanks for your response. I am creating some wikipages on mediawiki 1.33. My client is having a requirement that, if I print these pages then every printed page should have company logo in header of the page similar to word document. I am trying to print a wikipage which is actually getting printed in 3-4 pages. I am unable to get header in all the pages. Its coming only for the very first printed page. I have tried to put below code in common.css and print.css but no change in print preview of wikipages. I am unable to post sample code here as its not allowing me.